# Trace email without header or IP address

Tags: email

I have a gmail address only. It is a copy of the email. I do not have the original email. Is there anyway to trace it?

Answer (score 4):

## No.

You don't even have the email you are trying to "trace" let alone the headers.
Even if you somehow managed to convince someone to disclose whatever it is you're trying to "trace" you have no way to verify the authenticity. Sorry, but you're out of luck.